# hg summary --remote

Tags: mercurial

Is there any good detailed explanation of "hg summary --remote" command?
For instance, I need a list of possible values of "commit", "update" and "remote" lines.
BTW, I have no idea what "update" line means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--remote` options gives you a summarized version of the output of the `hg incoming` and `hg outgoing` commands.  See their help for an explanation.

As an aside, if you don't know what the 'update' line means you really should read up on some Mercurial basics.  The separation of traditional 'checkout' into 'pull' and 'update' is a core concept for Mercurial (or git).

Comment: Thanks, I've tested on my repositories, and since I had no repository which is not at head revision, I did not get what update line means.